# how to set date value or null in sql formatted query string for a date column

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a task to copy data from one db table to another db table using psycopg2 library in python language.

Now after fetching a row from first db I have to insert the row into the second db table, but the problem I face is that I need to format the query and insert the value for date column from a variable which may or may not have a date value, so my query is like the following:

```
cur.execute("""update table_name set column1 = '%s', column2 = '%s',column_date = '%s'""" % (value1, value2, value_date))
```

will now the `value_date` may be a `date` or a `None` value, so how to I convert this `None` value to sql `null` or something so that it can be stored in the date column.

Note: considering the `value1`, `value2` and `value_date` are variables containing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psycopg adapts a Python `None` to a Postgresql `null`. It is not necessary to do anything. If there is no processing at the Python side skip that step and update directly between the tables:

```
cur.execute("""
    update t1
    set column1 = t2.c1, column2 = t2.c2, column_date = t2.c3
    from t2
    where t1.pk = t2.pk
"""
```

This is how to pass `date` and `None` to Psycopg:

```
from datetime import date

query = '''
    update t
    set (date_1, date_2) = (%s, %s)
'''
# mogrify returns the query string
print (cursor.mogrify(query, (date.today(), None)).decode('utf8')) 
cursor.execute(query, (date.today(), None))

query = 'select * from t'
cursor.execute(query)
print (cursor.fetchone())
```

Output:

```
update t
set (date_1, date_2) = ('2017-03-16'::date, NULL)

(datetime.date(2017, 3, 16), None)
```

Comment: You mean if my query results in this:

cur.execute("""update table_name set column1 = '%s', column2 = '%s',column_date = '%s'""" % ('name', 'lasname', None))

willl it work????

Comment: tnx for the help, I will let you know when I try it

Comment: One thing I want to point out is that both the tables on two different dbs, and my query will be converted to the following forms depending on the value:

update table_name set column1 = 'somevalue', column2 = 'someothervalue',column_date = '2017-02-02'

or

update table_name set column1 = 'somevalue', column2 = 'someothervalue',column_date = 'None'

which the case with None is not accepted.

Comment: @WalidMashal Do not use the string `'None'`. Use the real `None` value: `column_date = None`

Comment: If the following is my query:

`cur.execute("""update duty_duty set 
                                                            duty_status_id = %s,to_date = %s,
                                                            from_date = '%s',
                                                            active = '%s' where id = %d""")`

The follwing error is shown when I don't use single quotes:

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist
LINE 2: ...                         duty_status_id = 33,to_date = None,

Comment: The query is either formatted with '%s' or %s, if we format it with '%s' then it won't accept 'None' but if we format it with %s then the query won't accept 2011-03-05 (a real date), that is basically the problem.

Comment: @WalidMashal I posted an example on how to do it.